# Custom delegate in PySide

Tags: python, qt, delegates, pyside

I've been trying to get a tabeView to display one of its columns as comboBoxes. In order to do this, I've written the code for a custom delegate:

```
class comboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
    super(comboBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
    self.parent= parent
    self.model= model

def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

    if not index.isValid():
        return False

    self.currentIndex=index  

    self.comboBox = QComboBox(parent)
    self.comboBox.setModel(self.model)
    value = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
    self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(value)

    return self.comboBox

def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    value = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
    editor.setCurrentIndex(value)

def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):

    if not index.isValid():
        return False

    index.model().setData(index, editor.currentIndex(), Qt.EditRole)

def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    currentIndex= index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)

    opt= QStyleOptionComboBox()
    opt.rect= option.rect
    currentComboIndex= self.model.createIndex(currentIndex,0)
    opt.currentText= self.model.data(currentComboIndex, Qt.DisplayRole)

    QApplication.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt, painter)
```

The problem is that when I try it the comboBox doesn't show any text at first (only once you've clicked on it). It seems the currentText property isn't working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if `self.model.data(currentComboIndex, Qt.DisplayRole)` actually returns a valid string?

Comment: Thank you and yes, it does return a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should call parent class paint() method. Add:

```
QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
```

at the end of the paint method in your class, after the call to `drawComplexControl`

Comment: Calling `QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)` completely undoes any painting that was done before it.  If you always call this as the last statement of `paint`, then you may as well not override `paint`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but you really don't have to deal with the painting at all. The combobox doesn't show a value because the combobox current index was likely set as a string instead of an int.

```
class ComboBoxDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    """ComboBox view inside of a Table. It only shows the ComboBox when it is
       being edited.
    """
    def __init__(self, model, itemlist=None):
        super().__init__(model)
        self.model = model
        self.itemlist = None
    # end Constructor

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        """Create the ComboBox editor view."""
        if self.itemlist is None:
            self.itemlist = self.model.getItemList(index)

        editor = QtGui.QComboBox(parent)
        editor.addItems(self.itemlist)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(0)
        editor.installEventFilter(self)
        return editor
    # end createEditor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        """Set the ComboBox's current index."""
        value = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        i = editor.findText(value)
        if i == -1:
            i = 0
        editor.setCurrentIndex(i)
    # end setEditorData

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        """Set the table's model's data when finished editing."""
        value = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, value)
    # end setModelData
# end class ComboBoxDelegate
```

This delegate will only show the combo box when the item is being edited otherwise it shows a normal text item delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `QStyledItemDelegate.displayText()` method to make your delegate display text without reimplementing paint(). Something like

```
class comboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    ...
    def displayText(self, value, locale=None):
        return get_appropriate_text_representation_for_value(value)
```